# when my flutter app is running. notifications are getting fetched I can see that by print statement but the fetched notifications are not displaying

Tags: android, firebase, notifications

Basically, I want notification to be displayed on android because I am not testing on iOS device

I am expecting notification to be displayed when my app is opened as I have wrote code for that purpose only.

When I am sending notification from firebase to my flutter app Notification is reaching to my application I can see that in logs as I have used print statement. But, Notification is actually not getting displayed on the screen.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="high_importance_channel" />
```

**notification_services.dart**

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';



class NotificationServices {
  FirebaseMessaging messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  Future<void> requestNotificationPermission() async {
    NotificationSettings setting = await messaging.requestPermission(
        alert: true,
        announcement: true,
        badge: true,
        carPlay: true,
        criticalAlert: true,
        provisional: true,
        sound: true);

    if (setting.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print("user granted permission");
    } else if (setting.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.provisional) {
      print("user granted provisions permission");
    } else {
      print("user denied permission");
    }
  }

  Future<String> getDeviceToken() async {
    String? token = await messaging.getToken();
    print("Token Is:$token");
    return token!;
  }

  void isTokenRefresh() {
    messaging.onTokenRefresh.listen((event) {
      event.toString();
    });
  }

  Future<void> showNotification(RemoteMessage message) async {
    AndroidNotificationChannel channel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
        Random.secure().nextInt(100000).toString(),
        'High Importance Notifications',
        importance: Importance.max);

    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
            channel.id.toString(), channel.name.toString(),
            channelDescription: 'your channel description',
            importance: Importance.high,
            priority: Priority.high,
            ticker: 'ticker');

    const DarwinNotificationDetails darwinNotificationDetails =
        DarwinNotificationDetails(
            presentAlert: true, presentBadge: true, presentSound: true);

    NotificationDetails notificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: darwinNotificationDetails);

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          0,
          message.notification!.title.toString(),
          message.notification!.body.toString(),
          notificationDetails);
    });


  }

  Future<void> initLocalNotifications(
      BuildContext context, RemoteMessage message) async {
    var androidInitializationSettings =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iosInitializationSettings = const DarwinInitializationSettings();

    var initializationSetting = InitializationSettings(
        android: androidInitializationSettings, iOS: iosInitializationSettings);

    await _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSetting,
        onDidReceiveNotificationResponse: (payload) {});
  }

  void firebaseInit() {
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((message) {
      print("Title is : ${message.notification!.title.toString()}");
      showNotification(message);
    });
  }
}
```

**home_screen.dart**

```
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
    notificationServices.requestNotificationPermission();
    notificationServices.firebaseInit();
    notificationServices.getDeviceToken().then((value) {

    });
  }
```